# RecyclerView no scrollbar when overscroll is turned off

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to avoid the overscroll shadow on the `RecyclerView`. However, it seems that adding `android:overScrollMode="never"` has the side effect of hiding any vertical and horizontal scrollbars that were present in the `RecyclerView`. Does anyone know how to have scrollbars showing while avoiding the overscroll shadows?

Comment: maybe you can try `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

Comment: I have that added and it doesn't do anything :(

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure that my answer will be correct, but i had the same problem with visability of scrollbars in `RecyclerView`. And it wasn't caused by `android:overScrollMode` property.
In my case the reason was that scollbars of `RecyclerView` doesn't work properly on some old devices if the `android:background` property is not set. Try to set it to any color or to transparent

Comment: hello, thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately this isn't the case for me as I can see the scrollbar when `overScrollMode` is set to default and then the scrollbar disappears when `overScrollMode` is set to `never` :(

Comment: @Jin I have the same problem as yours, and smbd uknow is right. Setting the background explicitly solves the issue.

Comment: Wonderful! I set a `@android:color/transparent` to `android:background` then get the proper scrollbar without over scroll effect.

Comment: Well.. brand new Samsung tablet in 2022 also needs `android:background` to draw scrollbar.

Answer (score 16):

Just to make the answer complete:

RecyclerView doesn't draw scrollbars due to willnotdraw flag. This flag is set to true, when neither the background nor the edge effects (`overScrollMode="never"`) are there. It's a drawing code optimisation for layouts. It should also be affected by the state of either of the scrollbars.

To fix it properly without setting the background you have to call `setWillNotDraw(false)`